# Bot Telegram PHP Send Object Parameters to last Command

Tags: php, bots, telegram-bot

I have question about Bot Telegram PHP, My Bot is success send request with this format nilai(space)[value].

Rolls :

1. User : send message : nilai(space)IT602
2. Bot : send message : show object data for code IT602

I want change format nilai(space)[value] to this rolls.

1. User : send message -> nilai <- this is command like /nilai
2. Bot : send message -> please input the nilai code for example : IT601
3. User : send message -> IT602
4. Bot : send message -> show object data for code IT602

This is My code with format nilai(space)[Value].

```
function prosesApiMessage($sumber)
{
    $updateid = $sumber['update_id'];

    if(isset($sumber['message']))
    {
        $message = $sumber['message'];

        if(isset($message['text']))
        {
            prosesPesanText2($message);
        } 
    }


    return $updateid;
}

function prosesPesanText2($message)
{
    $idpesan = $message['message_id'];

    $balas = $message['reply_to_message'];

    $pesan = $message['text'];
    $idchat = $message['chat']['id'];
    $namamu = $message['from']['first_name'];
    $iduser = $message['from']['id'];


    //untuk memisahkan antara format dan inputan
    $pecah = explode(' ', $pesan, 3);
    $katapertama = strtolower($pecah[0]);


    switch ($katapertama) 
    {
        case 'nilai':
            sendApiAction($idchat);
            if(isset($pecah[1])) 
            {
                $inputKode = $pecah[1];
                // this funtion for show data nilai by code
                $text = lihatNilai($iduser,$inputKode);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $text = "Gagal menampilkan nilai.\n";
                $text .= "Format Nilai  Nilai (Kode Matkul)";
            }

            // sendMessageReply($idpesan, $idchat, $text);
            sendApiKeyboard($idchat, $text, $keyboard_fungsi);  
            break;

        case 'id':
            sendApiAction($idchat);
            $text = "ID User Anda adalah ".$iduser;
            sendMessage($idchat, $text);
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }

}
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You must save a user's "state" and check for it on every message.
E.g. in pseudocode:

```
on message {
    if ($states[user_id] === 'expect nilai code') {
        sendMessage(user_id, ' show object data for code'.$text);
        $states[user_id] = null;
    } else {
        if ($msg_text === '/nilai') {
            $states[user_id] = 'expect nilai code';
            sendMessage(user_id, 'please input the nilai code for example : IT601');
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that `$states` stores a state for every user. Depending on the state you know where a user is in its process of answering your question.
If you set up your bot to use a webhook, make sure to save this array to your file system at the end of your script and read it on the start of your script. (e.g. with (`file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`).

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, yes I'm using webhook file_get_contents (//input). That state like temporary memory? Can i using file_put_contents () for write and read variabel $state?

Comment: It is temporary memory and yes, you will have to save it somehow.